# Selecting first different value in panda series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Panda Series such as

```
0  A
1  A       
2  B       
3  B       
4  A
5  B
6  B
7  B
8  A
```

I need to select the first different value every time, so the result should look like

```
0  A   
2  B       
4  A
5  B
8  A
```

I can do this with a simple loop and a tracking variable but I need to apply this to massive dataframes/series. Is there a vectorized/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try a [boolean index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 
                           3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 
                           6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'A'}})

print(df[df['val'].ne(df['val'].shift())])
```

Output:

```
  val
0   A
2   B
4   A
5   B
8   A
```

---

The boolean index finds locations where the current value does not match the previous:

```py
print(df['val'].ne(df['val'].shift()))
```

Generates:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
Name: val, dtype: bool
```

True indexes are kept, False are excluded.